# Unable to get the Query Results

Tags: mysql, sql

i am a newbie to SQL. i am not able to figure out what is the solution to this question where i have to filter a query through date.
Please have a look at this image.
[image]

Please tell me Where am i doing it wrong.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sentence appointing to what you are doing wrong. In this case, it is a typo: date is missing 0.

Comment: select * from results where away_team='Hessle' and played_on >= '2015-10-01'
Try this

Comment: No problem, Marc

Answer (score 1):

Your date should be 2015-10-01. You're missing a zero in the day portion.